# Matplotlib 2 y values against each X

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 2 RMSE values that I want to plot on the `y` axis against each `x` value I am holding, using `matplotlib` library. 
Here is my current try:

```
def plotRMSE(rmses):
    #Both values in each subarray must be plotted on the y axis at the same x point
    #rmses = [[15, 30], [10, 25], [18.45, 23.1], [3.2, 6.36], [2.4, 1.86e-10], [1.627, 3.3e-10]]
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.scatter(x[i], rmses[i])
    plt.show()
```

This of course returns `ValueError: x and y must be the same size`. I couldn't find any such examples (or any other suitable graph type). Is there a nicer solution than pairing up each value of `x[i]` with both values of each subarray?

Edit:
I was being silly. I can just use `rmses[i][0]` and `rmses[i][1]`, in two seperate `plt.scatter()` calls. Doing this will result in differing coloured points (which I didnt want; I wanted each `[0]` and `[1]` to be represented by the same colour and legend label), so here is my finished code for that:

```
def plotRMSE(rmses):
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
    plt.xticks(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.scatter(x[i], rmses[i][0], c="#555FFF")
        plt.scatter(x[i], rmses[i][1], c="#CC0000")
    plt.legend(["Train RMSE", "Test RMSE"])
    plt.show()
```

Cheers.

Comment: Can you also post some example input data?

Comment: Its in the code comments

Comment: why not put it in as actual sourcecode?

Comment: Either use Augstin's solution below, or change the line to `plt.scatter([x[i], x[i]], rmses[i])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    def plotRMSE(rmses):
        #Both values in each subarray must be plotted on the y axis at the same x point

        x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
        for i in range(len(x)):
            print(x[i])
            print(rmses[i][0])
            plt.scatter(x[i], rmses[i][0])
            plt.scatter(x[i], rmses[i][1])
        plt.show()

rmses = [[15, 30], [10, 25], [18.45, 23.1], [3.2, 6.36], [2.4, 1.86e-10], [1.627, 3.3e-10]]

plotRMSE(rmses)
```

Does this do what you want?

This seems the easiest solution without changing the format of the data, however I would generally have two response (y) vectors, y_1 and y_2.
Then just do:

```
plt.scatter(x, y_1)
plt.scatter(x, y_2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you compute `rmses` as a 2×N list of lists, but you
can transpose the N×2 list of lists using the Python idiom `zip(*listoflists)`

After the proper initialization

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
rmses = [[15, 30],
         [10, 25],
         [18.45, 23.1],
         [3.2, 6.36],
         [2.4, 1.86e-10],
         [1.627, 3.3e-10]]
```

it's relatively easy

```
for rms in zip(*rmses): plt.scatter(x, rms)
```

[image]

Adding a legend is a bit more involved, but not that much

```
for rms, lbl in zip(zip(*rmses),('first', 'second')):
    plt.scatter(x, rms, label=lbl)
plt.legend();
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Probably something like this could work:

```
def plotRMSE(rmses):
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(rmses[i])):
            plt.scatter(x[i], rmses[i][j])
    plt.show()
```